# Meteor iron router in production server

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Problem in meteor project after bundle in production server.This is error.Please help me.

```
  Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) }
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you passing in the `id` to your `data` function. My Thought would be that since a user initially routes to your page their is no data that gets rendered due to `this.params.id` being undefined on initial route.

Answer (score 0):

You've to define the route path: `path:'/:_id?'`. The ´?´ means that `_id` is optional. In your example you're try to load a route that doesn't accept and `_id`.

Comment: Please provide the example.@Mário

Comment: Router.map(function() {
  this.route('main', {path: '/'});
  this.route('api');
  this.route('admin'); });  this my router.Any thing wrong here.